# In regards to Facebook publish_actions permissions

Tags: facebook-graph-api, publish-actions

During the review process they stated "Make sure the user message area is not pre-filled in any way by the app otherwise the submission will be rejected. This includes hashtags, URLs, and any other text not written by the user."

This was our mistake having not noticed this in the new rules, but now begs the question... Does it follow their guidelines to just not pass a message at all?

I can't find any clarification on this.

Answer (score 2):

That´s not a "new" rule, it´s been in the policy since many years ;)

Anyway, not passing a message at all should be no problem at all, but you should always try to avoid publish_actions and use the dialogs instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui

Comment: Dialogs should only be used when extremely necessary: whether it's for facebook sharing or otherwise. A good design has no scenes that aren't absolutely necessary. There many situations where it makes more sense to ask for permission once and then share always. The user should have a means to turn off said permission within the app (e.g. Settings page). But a dialog every time is often a bad design policy. It's the price to pay for using Facebook integration, then that's that. But it's terrible design to see this as the "always" rule.

Comment: i disagree, dialogs should ALWAYS considered to be used first. one major benefit is that you don´t even need to authorize the user for them. official is always better than something you build on your own. autoposting is not allowed anyway, you MUST show the user some possibility to approve every single post on his wall (asking for permission does not just allow you to post without separate approval). prefilling is not allowed either, so it´s better to just use the official ways - you can´t do anything illegal that way.

Comment: anyway, it was just a side note to the answer - which is only "not passing a message is ok".